# Inserting values from table into different table with python or awk

Tags: python, awk

I have a tab-delimited table in a file (file-A) that looks like this:

```
ind1   A1   B1   C1   
ind2   A2   B2   C2   
ind3   A3   B3   C3
```

and one column of values in another file (file-B) ordered as follows:

```
ind1
X1
Y1
ind2
X2
Y2
ind3
X1
Y2
```

I would like to combine the two files such that the values listed under each individual in file-B (ind1, ind2, etc.) become inserted "in between" values corresponding to each individual in file-A. Here's what the output should look like for this particular case:

```
ind1   A1   X1   B1   Y1   C1
ind2   A2   X2   B2   Y2   C2
ind1   A3   X3   B3   Y3   C3
```

Comment: Have you attempted the problem? If so, how did it not work? People will help you if you have a specific problem, but you appear to just be asking us to do something for you.

Comment: Is this a python question or an awk question? If you can't even decide that much, I doubt anyone can or will bother to try answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your example has errors:

file2 should end with

```
X3
Y3
```

and the last line of output should be:

```
ind3 .....
```

**this awk oneliner works for your example`:**

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{print $1,$2,a[(FNR-1)*3+2],$3,a[FNR*3],$4}' file2 file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  head file file2
==> file <==
ind1    A1      B1      C1
ind2    A2      B2      C2
ind3    A3      B3      C3

==> file2 <==
ind1
X1
Y1
ind2
X2
Y2
ind3
X3
Y3

kent$  awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{print $1,$2,a[(FNR-1)*3+2],$3,a[FNR*3],$4}' file2 file
ind1    A1      X1      B1      Y1      C1
ind2    A2      X2      B2      Y2      C2
ind3    A3      X3      B3      Y3      C3
```